# postgres min() slower than min() with group by

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, aggregate

I'm using Postgres 12.10 AWS RDS. My query to find a min date using a group by is faster than just a regular min on the date. I'd like the regular min to be as fast but not sure if I'm putting in the wrong indices or I need to tune another parameter.

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.ed
(
    isd character varying(90) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    e_id character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    d_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ed_pkey PRIMARY KEY (isd, e_id)
)
```

Indices:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_ed_d_date
    ON public.ed USING btree
    (d_date ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_ed_e_id
    ON public.ed USING btree
    (e_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Query without just `min` takes 3 minutes:

```
select min(d_date)
from ed
where e_id = '62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf';
```

Explain Analyze for query:

```
Result  (cost=171.70..171.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=186940.968..186941.463 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.56..171.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=186940.963..186940.964 rows=1 loops=1)
          ->  Index Scan using ix_ed_d_date on ed  (cost=0.56..2214942.25 rows=12943 width=8) (actual time=186940.961..186940.962 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (d_date IS NOT NULL)
                Filter: ((e_id)::text = '62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf'::text)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 30539883
Planning Time: 0.195 ms
Execution Time: 186941.491 ms
```

While the query with the group by takes less than a second:

```
select min(d_date)
from ed
where e_id in ('62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf')
group by e_id;
```

Explain Analyze:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..5365.73 rows=2319 width=33) (actual time=92.093..92.095 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: e_id
  ->  Index Scan using ix_ed_e_id on ed  (cost=0.56..5277.83 rows=12943 width=33) (actual time=6.753..90.622 rows=6698 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((e_id)::text = '62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf'::text)
Planning Time: 0.098 ms
Execution Time: 92.127 ms
```

I get the same result, but why is the simpler query using the `d_date` index? How can I make the simple `min(d_date)` without `group by` as performant as the one that uses the `group by`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf'` seems to be a frequent `e_id`, so PostgreSQL thinks that it can win by looking at the rows in `d_date` order until it finds one with the correct `e_id`. Unfortunately all rows with `e_id = '62e2032b029b036ba25c73cf'` have high `d_date`, and PostgreSQL has to skip 30 million rows until it finds a hit.

You can prevent PostgreSQL from using the index if you use `min(d_date + INTERVAL '0')`. Then the first query should be as fast as the second.

Creating a composite index on `(e_id, d_date)` would be the perfect solution to the problem, then PostgreSQL cannot choose the wrong index by mistake.

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer
LINE 1: select min(d_date + 0)
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 26

Comment: Who would come up with a `timestamp` column and name it `date`? Anyway, I'll update the answer.

Comment: agreed. that was bad naming. your suggestion does work. is there anything else besides adding this hack to the query to get the same performance? ORM frameworks would not know about about this extra requirement.

Comment: Sure, you can drop the index on `d_date`.

Comment: I do use that `d_date` index in other queries.. I guess I'll have to use this particular `INTERVAL` hack..

Comment: A composite index on `(e_id, date)` might also help choosing a better plan (and then you can remove the single `(e_id)` index.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ wow. that one worked really well!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Of course. i took the liberty to add it to the answer.